# Guardar y Actulizar arrays de documentos creado dinamicamente

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Buenas muchachos, me encuentro trabajando con mongodb y mongoose, y tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo una colección que esta conformada por un campo, que debe ser un array (`yearsData` que se vera abajo) que guardara a manera de histórico registros de otros años, algo como esto (resultado esperado):

```
{  
   "id":"123456",
   "yearsData":{  
      "2015":{  
         "sales":"123456"
      },
      "2016":{  
         "sales":"1324"
      }
   }
}
```

Donde yearsData se guardara cada nuevo año, el problema que tengo es que estoy usando este código:

```
if(typeof g === 'undefined' || g === null) {
   goals.save(function(err, doc){
   if (err) bro.debug('err ', err);
   else
       bro.debug('Survery Saved');
});
}
else{
    Goals.findOneAndUpdate({userId: user.id},{$set:{ yearsData: JSON.stringify(dataHistorical)}}, {upsert: true, multi: false, new: true}).exec();
}
```

Pero cuando emulo el siguiente año, o el anterior (que no están en mi colección), me actualiza el registro que ya tengo, en otras palabras no lo guarda en el array (yearsData) sino que me deja un solo registro. Si pruebo con el 2015 obtengo esto:

```
{  
   "id":"123456",
   "yearsData":{  
      "2015":{  
         "sales":"123456"
      }
   }
}
```

Y si pruebo con el 2016 obtengo esto:

```
{  
   "id":"123456",
   "yearsData":{  
      "2016":{  
         "sales":"1324"
      }
   }
}
```

aunque se que el problema esta en el `findOneAndUpdate` no se como hacer para que si el registro esta lo actualize y si no esta lo guarde dentro del array `yearsData`.

Edit también he probado este código de update:

```
Goals.findOneAndUpdate({userId: user.id}, { yearsData: JSON.stringify(dataHistorical)}, {upsert: true}).exec();
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar la [notación de punto](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) para acceder a los elementos que están anidados.

Actualiza tu registro:

```
Goals.findOneAndUpdate({userId: user.id}, {$set: {"yearsData.2016.sales": "12345678"}}, {upsert: true}).exec();
```

Crea un nuevo registro:

```
Goals.findOneAndUpdate({userId: user.id}, {$set: {"yearsData.2017.sales": "123"}}, {upsert: true}).exec();
```